# Olympic statistics Question

Tags: statistics

An Olympic boxer comes from a region in Russia with the following demographic statistics.
                         Population
Russians          4,522,962 88.3%
Armenians   281,680 5.5%
Ukrainians  83,746  1.6%
Tatars        24,840.      0.5%
 Greeks    22,595.      0.4%
Georgians   17,826  0.3%
Belarusians 16,890  0.3%
Adyghe         13,834    0.3%
Romani        12,920.       0.3%
Germans      12,171    0.2%
Azerbaijanis    10,165  0.2%
Turks        8,527        0.2%
Moldovans   5,170   0.1%
Assyrians          3,764.      0.1%
Others       79,768

Question: What are the chances of this Boxer having Russian ethnicity?

Comment: $$\frac{88.3}{100}= \frac{883}{1000}$$

Comment: Assuming that "being an Olympic boxer" and the ethnicity are independent, $88.3$%, of course.

Answer (score 2):

$88.3\%$ is Russian.

Therefore, the chance that the boxer is Russian is $88.3\cdot0.01=0.883$.

This assumes that being an olympic boxer and ethnicity are independent, which is not necessarily true in the real world. However, it is probably close enough to be true to assume these to be independent for this question.